# Tamanho dos endereços de memória

Tags: memória

Estava vendo um vídeo onde um cara fala que sua arquitetura de 32 bits o endereço de memoria e 1 byte , mas não seria 4 bytes?

Answer (score 3):

Sim, um endereço de memória que tenha um tamanho de 32 bits necessariamente ocupará 4 bytes na memória.